# How to run a <script> element containing JavaScript that you get from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have an AJAX call that returns this javascript: `<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> alert('Hello World!') </script>.` . I tried appending it to the 'body' and 'head' elements of the DOM in the callback function, but neither caused the script to execute. How can I make it run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Get **Hello World!** as a result of ajax call and show alert after getting the result.

Comment: See 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197585/163643

Comment: @Andrew I tried j query's getScript but it didn't like the <script></script> tags. That's how I'm receiving the data. There are more than 1 pair of those and I really rather not go through the trouble of trying to remove them. It doesn't look like eval() will like those tags either.

Comment: @Ravindra hello world was just an example, the code is actually pretty complex. I just put in the alert to see if *anything* would execute.

Answer (score 0):

Look at JS eval()  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP

When you get your response back, add it to the body, then use jquery to pull out the string and eval it.

```
$.get( url, function(data) {
    var d = $('<div/>').appendTo($('body')).append(data);
    eval($('script', d).text());
    d.remove();
  }
)
```

'<div/>' is a literal, used to create a node (disposed of after being used) in the DOM, as a placeholder for your js code.

The code above will work for multiple '<script/>' fragments, too.

Comment: Jquery has $.getScript() method, by the way

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a noob. Is that '<div/>' literal or do I replace it with something?

Answer (score 0):

Make you server return the code *without* the *script* tag, then run it creating a function

```
(new Function('alert("Hello World")'))()
```

If you can't avoid the *script* tag before, you can remove it with a regular expression before applying

```
var data = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello world")</script>';
var regex = /<[^>]*script[^>]*>(.*)<\/[^>]*script[^>]*>/;
data.replace(regex,"$1")
```

or even splitting the string at specific characters (not a good choice, for obvious reasons: you mess the string, your code won't run anymore)

```
var data = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello world")</script>';
data.substr(31,data.length - 40);
```

The first option is way better, performance wise.

If you really want to execute the code using the whole string as-is, you just have to be sure that the library you are using is not escaping your code.

Comment: I can get it to work without the <script> tags. The real script can be pretty long. I'm not good at regular expressions and I haven't been able to come up with one that strips out the only the script tags

Comment: The other answer is what you need, then. I edited the pseudocode with working js, you can try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me as a substitute for

```
<script></script>
```

... and works even in an HTML file loaded using AJAX!

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" onload="alert('test');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />
```

Try it. It uses an images 'onload' call to run the internal javascript whenever the included-by-data-uri, one-pixel image is loaded.